# Linear model with longitudinal data, predicting difference

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, linear-model, panel-data

I have a set of data for 2 visits in patients and I would like to see whether there is a effect of a difference of one variable on another. 
So, lets say, my variables are A, B, age + gender. I want to see the effect of (amount of change in B) on (amount of change in A).

Is it correct if I model this as

A(BL-FU) = B(BL-FU) + A(BL) + B(BL) + age + gender ?

Also age and gender effects both by A and B.

Please advice on the model. Thank you.

Comment: What are BL/FU?

Comment: Baseline and Follow-up values of each patients. Sorry about that.

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to see the effect of (amount of change in B) **on** (amount of change in A)"? Can you rephrase what the predicted variable is? And why do you have a doubt about your model?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. to rephrase, B variable has two measurements at two time points. A has two measurements at the same time points. Other words, for all patients, baseline A and B and followup A and B values are measured. I would like to see the effect of difference of B (baseline B - followup B) on difference of A (baseline A - followup A). My doubt is in the fact that Im trying to model the 'difference of A' as a function of 'difference of B' with baseline A and baseline B as covariates. Is it statistically correct? Also my other covariates, gender and age effect both A and B.

Comment: You should edit your question and add that you intend to use OLS for this problem, if I'm assuming correctly.